# R Reference Class: Field of type 'units'

Tags: r, units-of-measurement, reference-class

I have a reference class, one of the fields for which is a 'units' object from the R units package. My initial class definition looked like this:

```
MyClass = 
    setRefClass(
        "MyClass",
        fields = list(units_value = "numeric")
    )

uv = units::as_units(10, 'cm')

mc = MyClass(units_value = uv)
```

Which threw the following error:

```
Error: invalid assignment for reference class field ‘units_value’, should be from class “numeric” or a subclass (was class “units”)
```

So I tried to set the field class to `units` like so:

```
MyClass = 
    setRefClass(
        "MyClass",
        fields = list(units_value = "units")
    )

uv = units::as_units(10, 'cm')

mc = MyClass(units_value = uv)
```

But this throws a whole *new* error:

```
Error in refClassInformation(Class, contains, fields, methods, where) : 
class “units” for field ‘units_value’ is not defined
```

For the moment I've settled for using a non-typed class constructor, but this seems like such a simple problem that it's hard for me to believe there's no way to construct a Reference Class with a units object as a field. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"units"` is an S3 class, so doesn't have a formal class definition. To get an S3 class to be represented inside an S4 or reference class, you need to register it first as a formally defined class using `setOldClass`

We can see that there is no formal class definition for "units" if we do:

```r
library(units)

getClassDef("units")
#> NULL
```

But if we use `setOldClass`, we can see it becomes registered:

```r
setOldClass("units")

getClassDef("units")
#> Virtual Class "units" [in ".GlobalEnv"]
#> 
#> Slots:
#>                 
#> Name:   .S3Class
#> Class: character
#> 
#> Extends: "oldClass"
```

This now allows your second code block to work as expected:

```r
MyClass = 
  setRefClass(
    "MyClass",
    fields = list(units_value = "units")
  )

uv = units::as_units(10, 'cm')

mc = MyClass(units_value = uv)

mc
#> Reference class object of class "MyClass"
#> Field "units_value":
#> 10 [cm]
```

The alternative is to set the class as "ANY" instead of "units", but this always feels like a last resort if you are trying to stick to OOP principles.

<sup>Created on 2022-12-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>